# What does this pointer to pointer in a struct mean?

Tags: c, pointers

So I was given a struct:

```
struct Xxx
{
    struct Yyy{...};
    Yyy **yyys;             // matrix of yyys
};
```

I am confused about how pointer to pointer is related to a matrix?

And how can I initialize a new `Yyy` and a new `Xxx`?

Comment: Think of it as a 2 dimensional array. So you can create your columns with the first pointer and use the second one for rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first level pointer would point to an array of pointers, and each second level pointer would point to an array of `Yyy`.

They can be set up as follows:

```
struct Yyy **makeMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    int i;
    struct Yyy **result = malloc(rows*sizeof(struct Yyy *));
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        result[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(struct Yyy));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So 'result[i][j]'  points to a yyy? And why is it possible to use [x][y] on a struct pointer?

Comment: @GzAndy No, `result[i][j]` *is* a `Yyy`.  Each array index is dereferencing a pointer.